# the asynchronous callback-function (JSON) doesn't work in opera, safari and ie7

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer-7

please excuse my bad english..

my script works in firefox 5, ie 8, but not in ie7, opera 9.5, safari..

Each checkbox should be checked with a database query, whether it needs to be activated

the script:

```
$('.merkzettel').each(function(){   
        var name =  $(this).attr("value");
    var url = "istInMappe.php?id=" + session_id + "&bild=" + name;
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
            checken (data.checked, data.number);

    });
});
function checken (bool, number){
if (bool == "checked"){
    var elem = "#img" + number;
    $(elem).attr('checked','checked');  
}
```

}

The answer from the script (istInMappe.php?...) is correct in opera: 
{"checked":"unchecked","number":"1553"}
there's no error message..

But the function "checken" is not executed and the checkboxes were not checked, without error message..

The html / checkbox (as example)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="img1566"  class="merkzettel" name="merkzettel1566" value="img_1566.jpg"/>
```

I dont find the error. Have anyone an idea?
thanks a lot...
lizzy

---

i modified the script, now one request query the checkbox-numbers, which stored in db, but i have still the problem with opera, ie 7, safari etc.

maybe there is another way?

```
function checken (nummer){
    var elem = "#img" + nummer;
    $(elem).attr('checked',true);   

}


function start(){

    var url = "fileadmin/php/refreshCheckboxes.php?id=" + session_id;
    $.get(url,function(data){
        $.each(data.posts, function(i,data){
            //alert (data.number);
            checken (data.number);

        }); 
    });
 }

 $(".load").click(function()
 {
 start();
  return false;
  });
```

http://www.ruth-schuette.com/gesamtwerk/in-arbeit.html

I am very grateful for any idea, now that I had for days been working on it

Comment: You have a typo in the code. In JSON it is "number":"1553", but in code data.nummer

Answer (score 1):

You say that the JSON looks like this:

```
{"checked":"unchecked","number":"1553"}
```

but your code references "nummer", not "number":

```
checken (data.checked, data.nummer);
```

A couple of notes:

- You can get the value of an `<input>` with ".val()":

  ```
  var name = $(this).val(); // or just this.value
  ```
- When you set the "checked" property of a "radio" or "checkbox" input, you can just use a boolean, because that's how the browser will interpret the value anyway:

  ```
  $(elem).attr('checked', true);
  ```

*edit* — well I don't know why it's not working in Chrome. The HTTP requests all seem to happen, and the responses look OK, but the success handler is never called.

I would offer the suggestion that even if it did work, it's a really slow way to get that information. It'd be much better if you could figure out what's checked at the point you're preparing the page, or at least have a single call that returns the entire map.  Making all those HTTP requests is going to take a while.

Comment: Hi Pointy, 
nummer / number: its was a tapping(?) error in this posting only. I have your notes corrected. My problem still exits...

Comment: Well can you make sure that the code is **exactly** like the code that's actually running?  It's hard to help if I can't see the real stuff.  Also, you say that the JSON data has the value of "checked" as "unchecked"; is that also a typographic error?  If not, then the "if" statement in the "checken()" function would keep anything from happening.

Comment: Is it easier when i post the link? http://www.ruth-schuette.com/gesamtwerk/auswahl-kopie-2.html you must check any checkbox "in die Mappe legen" and that is stored in the database. The next page load will be checked this and the checkbox should be activated automatically.

Comment: OK now I see, but I don't know (yet) why it's not working in Chrome.

Comment: yes it is strange in IE8, firefox 5 everything works. not in ie7, opera, safari